# Mobilefirst 7.1 Custom Analytics does not works until successfully log in

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I was trying to implement custom analytics. As given in this [documentation](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/moving-production/operational-analytics/#analyticsLogs)

```
WL.Analytics.log({buttonPress: "buttonA"}, "press");
WL.Analytics.log({buttonPress: "buttonB"}, "press");
WL.Analytics.log({buttonPress: "buttonC"}, "press");
WL.Analytics.send();
```

I have observed that this analytics is not sent until I successfully login using one of our realms. Is this information correct? does custom analytics requires the user to be logged in. Or is this configuration issue.

Comment: This would depend on the security settings of your client application. Is your application protected with a user realm?

Comment: @VivinK yes. But we also have some public screens. I want to collect analytics for that.